# MIPS; How to get groups of numbers within a number?

Tags: split, numbers, mips

I'm trying to figure out a way of obtaining groups of numbers from a number in MIPS. What I mean by this is, say if I have a hex value of 0x123456789ABCDEF0, I'm trying to load groups of 2 at a time. For eg; load $t0 with the value 12 first, then do some operation and then 34, then 56, then 78 etc, etc until F0.

So, the first question is, assuming that the size of the entire value is 64 bits and each group is 8 bits each, what do I declare this in the .data segment as since its in hex?

And secondly, how do I go about obtaining the group of 2 from the hex value?

Kind regards

Comment: 1. Depends on the assembler - if it doesn't have a directive for declaring 64-bit data you could split the value into two words.    2. Use `lbu` to load one byte of data from memory, and do this in a loop where you increment the address to load from on each iteration.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get it working.